# Theoretical security of mining bitcoins

Tags: security, proof-of-work

Is it possible to change rules of mining bitcoin division?

1. rewrite P2P bitcoin client (or write maleware) which will be pretending that *fake* bitcoin client is legal, original client
2. distribute program more/less widely
3. then by *fake client* division of mining loot will be with *fake/own* rules (e.g. give more bitcoins to farm *X*, even if farm *X* didn't work more than others)

---

- no changing keys
- no faking difficulty level/spent time
- maybe changing proof-of-work action

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.
This is "hard-fork" (bitcoin with other rules) or "alt-coin" (any crypto-currency with its own rules)

Answer (score 1):

No. Your question is very hard to make sense but whatever any fake node does still requires the Proof Of Work which cannot be faked. Anything the fake node does (with or without proof of work) that's not according to the consensus rules will be rejected by other nodes. From that moment on the fake node is not dealing with bitcoin anymore no matter how hard it tries to put that label on it.